# Decrypt the series - find number of continuous sequences of integers such that their sum is zero

Tags: php, algorithm, performance, sequences

The following is a programming task.

You are given a sequence of N integers. The task is to find the number of continuous sequences of integers such that their sum is zero.

For example if the sequence is:
2, -2, 6, -6, 8
There are 3 such sequences:

- '2, -2'
- '6, -6'
- '2, -2, 6, -6'

I already have the following program written in PHP that reads the input from `STDIN` (first line containing the number of integers that follow.)

```
<?php

$n = fgets(STDIN) * 1;
$seq = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++) {
    $seq[] = fgets( STDIN ) * 1;
}

$count = 0;
for( $i = 0; $i < $n; $i++)
{
    $number = 0;
    for( $j = $i; $j < $n; $j++)
    {
        $number += $seq[$j];
        if( $number == 0 )
            $count++;
    }
}

echo 'count: ' . $count . PHP_EOL;
```

**Input example**

```
5
2
-2
6
-6
8
```

This works well for smaller sequences, but its efficiency is O(n^2).

What algorithm is appropriate - with possibly O(n) efficiency - for a sequence containing 100.000 integers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's assume your data is stored in an array, and let it be `arr`.
Create an array `sum`, such that:

```
sum[i] = arr[0] + arr[1] + ... + arr[i]
```

And, in addition a single entry at the beginning with 0 (to handle a subarray that starts at the beginning and sums to zero)

Now, it is easy to see that for each two indices `i,j` such that `i<j` and `sum[i]=sum[j]`, the continuous sequences `arr[i+1]+arr[i+2]+...+arr[j] = 0`.

By creating this array `sum`, you only have left to find how many duplicates are there. This cannot be done in `O(n)`<sup>1</sup> (this is the [element distinctness problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem)), but can be solved in `O(nlogn)` using sorting and then iterating and counting, which is still very fast for 100,000 entries.

Note, that if there are for example `n` duplicates of the number `k` in the array `sum`, there are `Choose(n,2) = n(n-1)/2` continuous subsequences that are generated for these duplicates.

**Example:**

```
arr = [1,2,-2,5,6,-6,-5,8]
sum = [0,1,3,1,6,12,6,1,9]
sorted(sum) = [0,1,1,1,3,6,6,9,12]
```

There are 3 duplicates of 1 and 2 duplicates of 6, so you have total of:

```
Choose(3,2) + Choose(2,2) = 3*2/2 + 2/2 = 3+1 = 4
```

Which indeed match the 4 subsequences:

```
2,-2
2,-2,5,6,-6,-5
6,-6
5,6,-6,-5
```

---

(1) Without hashing, and then you will decay to O(n^2) worst case, but will benefit from `O(n)` average case, at the cost of `O(n)` extra space.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the late reply.

Comment: for this to be complete you have to add additional entry into the sum array with zero, so : 
arr = [1,2,-2,5,6,-6,-5,8]
sum = [0, 1,3,1,6,12,6,1,9]
sorted(sum) = [0, 1,1,1,3,6,6,9,12]

This will solve the problem in some cases where the first item is part of a zero sequence

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't reply to comments, this is a reply to amit's answer.
Maybe I have something wrong, but when applying your method to the original test case, we don't get the right answer:

```
input = [2, -2, 6, -6, 8]
sum = [2, 0, 6, 0, 8]
sorted(sum) = [0, 0, 2, 6, 8]
```

Since there are 2 duplicates of the number 0, this gives us (2*1)/2=1, which is not correct (correct answer would be 3).
What am I missing? Thanks